# Updated Android SDK adds errors to my app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, callback, listener

So I recently updated my Android SDK to the newest version, and five errors have suddenly cropped up in my app.

Three of the errors involve me overriding the function onItemSelected(); the other two involve my overriding the functions onItemClick() and onNothingSelected() (once in a class ).

In all cases, the error message is:

```
The method [Method] of type [Type] must override a superclass method.
```

For some more context, in these cases I am:

- Creating a new OnItemSelectedListener and overriding onItemSelected and onNothingSelected
- Overriding onItemClick for a class that implements OnItemClickListener
- Creating a new Callbacks and overriding onItemSelected
- Overriding onItemSelected for a class that implements the Callbacks created in the third item

My app compiled and worked fine before updating the SDK (I previously had resources for API 16 installed, and installed those for API 17).

What might have changed?  What should I be looking for?

Comment: make sure your java compiler level is 1.6 or above

Comment: This site also lists what has changed between API 16 and API 17:  http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/17/changes.html Could be worth a look

Comment: Ah, yes, it was the compiler. Strange, I thought I had had this problem previously and fixed it then. Thanks!

Comment: You should add and accept the answer, just to mark this question as complete.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem appeared to be that my compiler level was set to 1.5 instead of 1.6.  I switched it to 1.6 and the error messages went away.